# Is it possible to infer second template argument type for this template class?

Tags: templates, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have a template class `A`

```
template<template<class> class E, class N>
class A
{}
```

and I also have a template function that takes `A` as an argument:

```
template<class T>
auto make_something(const T& t){}
```

used like `make_something(a)` on an object `a` of `A` type.

I would like to be able to tell what is the type `N` from inside the `make_something` function. Is there any way of achieving this without changing the template argument of `make_something`?

Comment: Can you show an example of code where you would use this stuff?

Comment: It is a bit complicated to show a real example. Why do you need that? A is a component used to build another object inside the make_something function, and N is a policy decided when you configure A that impacts the way the new object works.

Comment: There's an amount of approximation in your question. E.g. if `A` is a template, and `make_something` takes one type template parameter, then `make_something<A>` is nonsensical.

Comment: I agree. It was a short way to let you know that ‘a’ was of ‘A’ type. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In the following I've changed `template<class> class E` to `template<class, class> class E` because I used `std::vector`, which has two type template parameters, for `E`.)

I have no idea what you're doing, but to ask question about types, you need to write some traits.

I guess something like the following could be a starting point:

```cpp
// to ask if something is an A at all
template<typename T>
struct IsAnA : std::false_type {};
template<template<class, class> class E, class N>
struct IsAnA<A<E, N>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_an_A_v = IsAnA<T>::value;

// to query A's second template arg
template<typename T>
struct SecondTemplArgOfA {};
template<template<class, class> class E, class N>
struct SecondTemplArgOfA<A<E, N>> {
    using type = N;
};

template<typename T>
using second_templ_arg_of_A_t = typename SecondTemplArgOfA<T>::type;

// make use of it
template<class T>
auto make_something(const T& t){
    if constexpr (is_an_A_v<T>) {
        using its2ndTemplArg = second_templ_arg_of_A_t<T>;
        // so what?
    } else {
        // you've fed make_something with a non-A, so
        // you can't get its second template arg
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/dTb6dTxfs)

Comment: Thanks, it works. I had tried the same approach, but  I was missing `using second_templ_arg_of_A_t = typename SecondTemplArgOfA<T>::type;
`